# Leave empty space between top and bottom icons in Material-UI Drawer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

This is tough to put into words, but I want to be able to add two sets of icons to the Drawer component.
Set 1 goes to the top, aligned in a standard column, just like the examples they provide.
Set 2 goes at the bottom of the Drawer, leaving empty space between both sets while remaining responsive.

Here's a rough example in which xxx reprensents white space.

Icon 1
Icon 2
Icon 3
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
Icon 4
Icon 5

Is this doable while remaining responsive and avoiding custom CSS rules for margins and paddings?
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do without any CSS at all. The [Material-UI documentation for the Drawer](https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/) makes heavy use of CSS-in-JS to style also the basic examples.

But I don't think you have to write a lot of CSS to achieve this vertical gap between the icon groups. Using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox), and allowing the first group of icons to grow to the full available vertical space by setting `flexGrow: 1`, I believe you can achieve what you're after?

See [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-65159851-q1cc6) for a demo